# Require to select column, random column values from table

Tags: oracle

I want to select random column values from table without it repeating it random value from the second column

```
select signer,  ( (SELECT  SIGNER 
                   FROM TABLE SAMPLE(10) 
                   WHERE ROWNUM <= 1) )as signrand 
FROM TABLE ;
```

Actual output of the above query:

```
signer,                signrand   
____________________________________________
MICHAEL MCLEAN         BARRY NEVILLE PITT
BARRY NEVILLE PITT     BARRY NEVILLE PITT
GREGORY DONALD MILNE   BARRY NEVILLE PITT
GREGORY DONALD MILNE   BARRY NEVILLE PITT
GREGORY DONALD MILNE   BARRY NEVILLE PITT
BARRY NEVILLE PITT     BARRY NEVILLE PITT
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` analytical function in two subquery and different logic to order `signer` in `order by` clause then join them based on it(`rn`). It will prevent repetitive names as random value.

```
With dataa(signer, minl) as
(Select signer, 
        min(length(signer)) 
          over () as minl from table),
dataa_rand(signer, rnrand, rnnorm) as
(Select signer, 
        row_number() 
          over (order by substr(signer, dbms_random.value * (minl-1), 1)) as rnrand,
        row_number()
         over (order by signer) as rnnorm
  from dataa)
--
Select a.signer, b.signer
From dataa_rand a join dataa_rand b
On (a.rnnorm = b.rnrand)
```

You can use any logic to order the `signer`. My query is just a thought in correct direction.

Cheers!!